# Regex question was closed as lacking details, but I think it was objective and clear

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, deleted-questions, reopen-closed

This regex question was closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873954/two-regex-rules-not-working-in-google-data-studio

Before it was closed, [I answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877709), and I stand by that answer: I really think the question is fine as=is.  It describes the problem correctly, it is about programming, etc.

Why was the question closed? Could someone help me to understand what is wrong with it?

---

Despite the big discussion around the problem and the number of upvotes showing the question should not be closed, the question was marked as a duplicate of a SQL-related question (the original question is about Data Studio syntax, not SQL, although they share some similarity), and more recently it was completely deleted (?!?!).  WOW!  What's happening?

Comment: How do you know the OP didn't want both regexps to only ever work in conjunction? (That seems sort of the gist of using CASE - even if misguided.)

Comment: Its not a question about regex at  all. It's simply the person not understanding how `CASE` works in SQL.  Its very far away from being a regex question and therefore should be closed.  If they had actually asked about CASE instead, it would probably have been a duplicate of an existing SQL question eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-expression-syntax and therefore also should be closed.

Comment: @JK. Even if what you say about the question not being about regex at all is true, then that doesn't prove that the question should be closed. It means only that the question should be edited (including retagging) to better reflect what its *actual* topic is. And, if it's a duplicate, then that would be a valid closure, but the fact that a question is a duplicate does not (ever) justify closing it for any of the other close reasons.

Comment: I think it's part of a more broad problem of questions being answered -- and "answered" meaning the problem was solved -- and then being closed without appreciation of time invested by answerer, and without giving the answeree opportunity to acknowledge the problem was solved indeed.

Comment: @Sergey "Closed" doesn't have anything to do with whether or not a question has been answered.

Comment: @CodyGray People come here for help and to provide help. SO moderates in between. The key in my comment is "broad". Something is broken in process design.

Comment: The site is only designed and intended to support certain types of questions, @Sergey. The scope is extremely narrow. Questions that exist outside of that scope should not be answered here, regardless of whether or not they could be or someone wants them to be. Closure is how Stack Overflow deals with questions that do not meet our requirements, which are all stated clearly in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is not a help desk. We are *not* here to help people directly. We are here to build a library of high quality Q&A. That this also helps people is a nice side-effect.

Comment: I tried to salvage the question. Are you sure that you fully understood the problem in the question? It's not completely clear to me what the asker wanted to achieve. I guess the purpose might have been to apply two rules instead of only the first one... but maybe not. Maybe the answer was a bit premature.

Comment: There was no question in that post.

Comment: @Dexygen Meta Stack Overflow is a place for discussing issues that affect the main site. That goes for big and small matters. It's the place where the community can make policy, contest moderator decisions, ask for questions to be closed/reopened, and otherwise raise their concerns. It's also, of course, a place where people can go to report bugs and get support with using the site's features. I think it's quite unfair to call any of that "whining", although a fair bit of whining certainly does happen on Meta. Importantly though, this question doesn't need to have any more general application.

Comment: @Vega I assume the OP intended to write "as-is", meaning "without any need for a change" in that context.

Comment: With respect @CodyGray, many of the community members feel the exact opposite way: they come here to help people, and any contribution to building a database of Q&A is "a nice side-effect".

Comment: @SteveBennett And many feel the opposite way of that: They come here to contribute to a knowledge database, and helping individual people is "a nice side-effect".

Comment: To a certain extent everyone defines for him/herself what SO is and what it isn't. Within the bounds of the rules everyone is free to pursue own goals but the result will be some kind of average. Just take the question linked here as example: with 23 upvotes and 19 downvotes currently, one can surely say that the community is sometimes split. It's not a great question, but it's not a really bad one either. It's something in between.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830951/why-does-my-algorithm-stop-after-a-while#comment119894218_67830951 Also came across a question recently that was closed after an answer was given and accepted. Not regex-related.

Comment: @sneep There are *tons* of questions that are answered+accepted even though they should be closed. I've just cobbled together a canned comment for typo-answers, only to give up right away after becoming aware just how many there are. Just because people cannot close these fast enough does not mean they are fine.

Comment: I am always in favor of keeping a question open unless there is a VERY STRONG REASON TO CLOSE IT.  Sometimes, 'any port in a storm' applies to the questioner, or a person who finds it from the web.

Comment: @JosephDoggie 'any port in a storm' That's the thing. A bad question isn't a safe port, it's a fake port. The question here is rather trivial (don't use CASE then would be the direct answer). It's only valuable because Diego took the time and explained something but in truth he answered a different question there (how does the CASE statement work). And closing doesn't mean that we kill the port, only that the safe port is still a mile away and you have to invest a bit more in order to make it there.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that the question author did never show up again and improved the question. Maybe he/she was scared away by the meta effect (lots of comments, edits, votes) or maybe didn't care enough about it or something else. It looks like the question got effectively abandoned by the author.

Comment: Why would we care if the original author came back or not, @Trilarion? Stack Overflow is all about *content*, not people. It doesn't matter who originally contributed something, as long as it can be turned into a valuable addition to our knowledge base by the community. That is where the real magic of Stack Overflow lies. This is not a help desk; it doesn't matter if the original author *never* comes back, because many, many people beyond the original author can be helped.

Comment: @CodyGray But usually the guidance is that we should not go against the intent of the original author when editing. The original author may come back and can reject edits. Editors aren't on an equal footing with original authors, SO isn't Wikipedia (for better or worse). But I largely agree with you. Content basically belongs to everyone. That's why I edited the question. But still in this case I had hoped for that the original author comes back and takes part in improving the content.

Comment: @Trilarion and that's why it shouldn't be through as a policy. Heck Shog itself didn't believe it.

Comment: I would add I'd rather find a question with someone with the same problem (even if unanswered) then no question at all  .... at least it shows that it's not unique to my system.  (Example:  an obscure compiler error, with message seemingly unrelated to coe at hand)...  If it has really bad answers, that will become clear over time.

Comment: @CodyGray Several times you assert that SO is only a knowledge base, that we are not here to help people directly. You go on to quote a link to support this view. However, nothing in that linked page supports the clear notion that SO is not those things or is not intended to help people directly. In fact, the "tour" page directly highlights as the first thing:  **Ask questions, get answers, no distractions**. We tried the just a knowledge repo thing with SO Documentation and it failed. SO is here to directly help people though I concede that as a community we are free to try something else.

Comment: @JonSG We do both. We directly help people and we indirectly help even many more people. The question askers get answers and all visitors get answers too. If I'm not mistaken that was exactly the mission from the go. Now the question is here to whom questions belong, just to the asker or to everyone equally?

Comment: Your update isn't accurate, people are agreeing that it shouldn't be closed as unclear, not that it shouldn't be closed as any reason. There are plenty of targets duplicates about how case statements work. Google data studio implements the sql spec to some extent, therefore any sql question that explains how case statements work is a valid target.

Comment: @Braiam My update isn't accurate? The question was deleted as completely off-topic (this is the current status). Also, we have 3 answers in this post, all of them describes why there's no reason to close it (with several upvotes). What part is inaccurate? Nobody that thinks different posted an answer explaining why it should be deleted (only comments, with few upvotes).

Comment: @Braiam And your comment comparing Data Studio and SQL shows that you didn't work with Data Studio at all. Data Studio engine is very rudimentar compared to SQL. You can't write complex expressions (combining OR and AND operators) in case statements as you can in SQL, for example. Even some comparisons are not allowed. Their engine is different, their usage is different. They just share a similar syntax. Data Studio has no commitment to adhere to SQL-standards.

Comment: That's why I said "implements the sql spec to some extent". And as far as we are aware, case statements are implemented the same way they are in sql.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz I am not sure if you have read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408248/11573842) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408289/11573842). (if you haven't then they are worthy of a read). Also maybe it would be better if you asked a new, separate question instead of editing this one and link to it...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 Thanks for your comment. Actually, I though it was something bad to do (I mean, opening a new discussion for something that already has a discussion).

Comment: @Braiam Anyway, despite about our opinions about the difference from Data Studio to SQL, what part of my update is inaccurate? Notice the question was DELETED, not closed. I do not agree in closing it, but I may understand. But deletion is different...

Comment: I agree with Diego that this question most definitely should not be deleted. And the comparison between Data Studio and SQL is only remotely relevant. It is completely understandable that someone who uses Data Studio to dabble in some programming for the first time in their life doesn't _know_ that there are similarities, so they won't search in the SQL tags, they search in the Data Studio tags. This question has a place on this site if only to help direct future Data Studio-users to SQL questions that are relevant for their questions/issues.

Comment: @CodyGray as moderator who has followed this discussion somewhat, can you shed light on why the question is now completely deleted rather than retagged/closed with link to a duplicate (SQL) question?

Comment: @asontu The question has now been undeleted.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have no idea why that question might have been closed.

Regex questions that are perceived as asking for a regex to be written are often closed for this reason, rightly or wrongly, but this question wasn't even asking for a regex to be written.

It was asking for an explanation of the reasons behind an observed behavior, and it gave what seems to me to be a minimal, reproducible example of that behavior. It mentioned what regex engine was being used (Google Data Studio). I don't know what other information it might have been lacking.

I'm posting this answer first, instead of unilaterally voting to re-open, because I am not a regex expert, and I might be missing something obvious. At least one of the close-voters is someone whose opinions I generally trust, so I think it's appropriate to hold off on re-opening and give folks a chance to explain what I might be missing. But please do explain, if you think this question needs to stay closed!

Comment: The question misses the input, and it fails to describe the actual problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. In my book that's not a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Adding example strings and the expected output would have been enough to avoid closure.

Comment: I do not see why input examples are required. There is plenty of information provided to understand the question. The problem description is quite clear. It says a lot more than "it doesn't work".

Comment: @GeertBellekens: The actual problem description given was "*but only the first rule works. If I swap the order of the rules, this rule applies, but not the second one*."  That's *vastly* more specific than "it doesn't work" - it's fairly strong evidence that the OP wants *both* of them to apply to the same string, not just one or the other, otherwise there wouldn't be a problem to ask about.  It's not a *good* MCVE, but the answer was able to explain exactly what the answer does so future readers can just look at the answer.

Comment: Agreed that burden should normally be on the querent, so it's not exactly worthy of an upvote, but it's not unanswerable.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is a whole lot of guessing, or at least more than I'm willing to do. I still agree with the close votes.

Comment: @GeertBellekens: I don't think it was ambiguous enough to justify a close vote on that basis.  It certainly doesn't seem like much of a stretch to me; it's certainly the obvious thing that would explain someone having asked that question.  I likely wouldn't have answered, perhaps pending confirmation of what was wanted, but a keener version of myself that wasn't yet tired of answering low-effort / minimal-quality questions probably would have.

Comment: "I am not a regex expert" ...a _regexpert_ ?

Answer (score 35):

Regular Expressions is a tough topic for many users, and it's completely possible that someone asks a questions that shows they don't understand the matter well. I think this question is such a case. Therefore, it *makes sense* that the user has not asked a high-quality question that checks all the requirements for input/output on it.

However, the question does give **some very clear clues**:

1. What is not working?: "Two REGEX-Rules not working"
2. Where is the problem?: "in Google Data Studio"
3. What has the user tried?: "I used these combined REGEX-Rules"
4. What has worked?: "but only the first rule works."
5. Has the user tried something else? "If I swap the order of the rules, this rule applies, but not the second one"

I think this information is enough to qualify as a legitimate question in the RegEx topic. We can safely make an assumption that the user wants both rules to work. The answer provided by @Diego Queiroz is a good answer and has the potential to help the user a lot:

1. It clarifies how the `CASE` statements work
2. It clarifies how regular expressions will match
3. It gives an optimization
4. It gives an alternative regular expression that can *potentially* satisfy the user (but we should leave this to the user to decide).

Comment: It's not an amazingly high quality question but also nothing wrong with it. But it's not a legit question in the regex tag because the issue is really about CASE statements, the fact regex is being used is completely incidental to the actual issue. And how CASE statements work is something with a million answers already, so it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 14):

So, here's the thing: regex has nothing to do with the question at hand. A better MCVE would be the following:

```
case
  when Seite = 1 then 0
  when Seite = 2 then 1
  else -1
end
```

Yes, the question has a regex, and no, it's not relevant, as the answer provided (and the example above) made clear. But the case statement is not actually the problem either. The problem is that the OP wants to conditionally replace two strings and were thinking that case statements are the solution (the answer already tells them this). The title *almost* captured this, but then the asker involved regex and now there's an extra problem that shouldn't be there.

If users were more willing to edit out the problem with the solution and instead surface the underlying problem, it wouldn't be closed.

That seems like a representation of what the question wants:

> I have strings that can start with `/amp/` or end with hyphen plus some integers (like `-654654`). I want to remove these from my data. How do I do this?

Relevant read:

- [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213575)

Comment: Well the "you" here is not the one who asked the question on the main site, they are the one who answered the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat well, answerers complaining that questions they answered are closed, instead of editing them.... it's like we created a badge specifically for this...

Comment: It looks like this was intended as an answer on main site question.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that when you do use tags, you should generally read the wiki to make sure you've included all necessary details in your question. If the wiki is asking for details that are totally irrelevant to your question, then you probably shouldn't be using the tag. Reading the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) tag wiki would have headed off a lot of confusion.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica or the regex users should just remove it like java/javascript, c/c++/c# and python.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier no, I'm saying that the question is poorly framed.

Comment: @Braiam - Yeah, I'm not condoning the drive-by closure. But given the notoriously poor quality questions in the regex tag, I can understand why reviewers get so trigger-happy when closing questions that don't meet a minimum bar. No example inputs? Close. They don't bother to take the extra time to notice that it's not actually a regex question.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica meh, I don't blame them. When everything you see is garbage, it's difficult recognizing something that isn't.

Comment: @Braiam indeed, now that I read my edited version, that intent becomes clear ;-)

Comment: ... damnit I almost successfully camouflaged a post from Peter's piercing gaze. I'll get the extra spaces some day. ( space intentionally left because what you gonna do? flag my comment to edit the space out?!!! :D )

Comment: @Félix Who needs flags when there are moderators floating about who are also grammar pedants? ;-)

Answer (score 8):

As one of the close voters in the question, adding the 2 criteria that I look for in [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions:

1. Current Field / Values
2. Expected Field / Values

For example:

| Current Field | Expected Field |
| --- | --- |
| /abcd/amp/-1234 | /abcd/ |
| /text/amp/-1234 | /text/ |

A RegEx attempt is optional. Currently, the question only has a RegEx attempt.

As [mario](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) noted in the comments, "*How do you know the OP didn't want both regexps to only ever work in conjunction?*". The issue with answering a question without the current and expected values is that there is a risk that a user creates and answers their own understanding of the question - it creates ambiguity thus may be less useful for future users (in the current state).

Comment: You have a valid point about what you wish to see when looking at regex questions. But did you add a comment to that effect to the question? Without that comment, how could the OP ever know what you wanted to see?

Comment: @slugster: Noted! I tend to add a quick comment or upvote an existing one when voting to close questions (and answers) and then remove it once the question is closed (not entirely sure whether I had done so in this specific close case).

Comment: What's your main goal with being strict about these rules, even in cases like this where we can be 99% sure we can figure out what the querent wants?  Limiting the tide of low-quality questions that don't "deserve" answers if the person didn't put in much effort to following our standards? Or were you really primarily concerned with future readers being able to find the questions, and not cluttering up SO with low future value because of being hard to search?  If it's clear enough (even just barely) but too low effort, IMO we should just downvote.

Comment: Given that the answerer chose to take on the burden of responsibility of explaining exactly what their answer does, that removes the risk of future readers thinking they found what they wanted; you always have to read the question or answer to figure out whether your problem is the same, not just the title.  I agree normally the burden of explaining what is/isn't wanted should be on the querent, but an answer can do it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The aim was to get get clarity on the current and expected values; as noted by Trilarion "*I tried to salvage the question. Are you sure that you fully understood the problem in the question? It's not completely clear to me what the asker wanted to achieve. I guess the purpose might have been to apply two rules instead of only the first one... but maybe not. Maybe the answer was a bit premature.*" Also, note that I had voted to close the question when it was first created, and only saw the answer in the morning (after the question was closed). **The post has also been reopened**

Comment: On reading the question myself, I'm 99% sure I understand what they wanted, which seems sufficient.  A better [mcve] would be *nice*, but I disagree there was enough ambiguity to justify closing.  Future readers with a problem that matches Diego's answer might well find it.   (I probably wouldn't have bothered to answer a relatively low-effort question that seems to have missed the point of the switch/case concept, though, but I've been around on SO for years and already posted at least one version of what I have to say about a lot of things.  The title does seem reasonable searchable.)

Comment: Anyway, I understand that was your thought process and judgement at the time; thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks :) Understand what you're saying as well (had chosen MCVE - Minimal Complete Verifiable Example as the close reason), as the purpose was to gain clarity on the current and expected fields to reproduce the issue and find a solution. to reiterate, had voted to close before an answer was posted as the intention was to have an MCVE so that fellow users could provide a suggestion.

Comment: Close voting this question is not the right thing to do in this case. All the reasons I'm reading for closing this question are actually reasons to remove the regex-tag and explain to OP that you removed the regex tag because the regexes aren't the issue, their understanding of the Google-spreadsheets scripting language is the issue.

Comment: @asontu: Noted and for future reference, [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408243/12892553) has just updated the respective question and added a suggestion on the points raised.

Comment: @asontu If regex is removed, it is clear duplicate of SQL CASE question. No matter how you turn it, it should be closed.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar clear to you and me because we understand the shared syntax between SQL and Google Data Studio, not clear to OP who is using Google Data Studio, not SQL. So at the very least the question should then be closed as a duplicate of an existing SQL question with explanation for OP that the answer of that question is, in fact, applicable to their Google Data Studio question.