# Should posts that are actively being discussed on Meta be temporarily exempt from deletion?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, rules

When a question on the Main site is brought up for discussion on Meta, I add the following comment on the Main question

> This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

(the link is to the actual question on Meta, of course). The purpose of this comment is to notify the OP, answerers, and other visitors of the increased attention on the post. Also, this helps with avoiding accidental actions from SOCVR, which has restrictions on this.

However, this doesn't prevent delete votes being cast on the Main question, and given that Meta regulars include users with the delete privilege, and strong views that they're not afraid to express, it's not uncommon for posts to be deleted very soon after they're brought up on Meta. This means a *substantial* number of users, (i.e. <10k rep), can no longer fully participate in the discussion. Even if screenshots are provided, they tend not to include screenshots of the answers, and so potentially relevant context is lost for those users.

I think there should be a restriction on delete votes being cast on questions for a period after they're brought up on Meta. This should apply to answers as well, if that's part of the focus of the  Meta post. Of course, there would be an exception for Meta posts that say "Please delete this ...". However, these Meta posts are relatively rare, and are usually frowned upon. I've been guilty of making such Meta posts myself, and have been informed, in no uncertain terms, to cut it out, and I think that makes sense in general. Another exception would be potential spam/troll posts that are brought up for discussion. While flags should be raised in those cases, there shouldn't be a restriction on deleting that content either.

I was under the impression that moderators would not be inclined to impose and enforce such a restriction, and so I thought this wouldn't be a rule that could be established. However, a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873954/why-is-only-the-first-case-statement-applied-in-a-google-data-studio#comment119985817_67873954) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873954) recently brought up on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408223) indicates otherwise

> **Moderator Note:** We will not be deleting questions while they are under active discussion on Meta. Please note that having participated in the deletion of this question within the next 48 hours will likely result in the suspension of your account. – Cody Gray ♦

This seems reasonable to me (at least that this shouldn't be allowed, not that users should be suspended without a warning first, but that's an enforcement detail). The 48 hour limit also feels about right, but perhaps it should be closer to a week. So it seems that at least one moderator is willing to enforce such a rule, unless I'm reading too much into that comment.

Given that the "rule" has been codyfied ;), does the community think it should be codified?

Note that this is a much more constrained version of [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191), as it only addresses delete votes, for the purpose of allowing all users to be able to participate in the discussion, and is not intended as a system constraint, but would be handled by moderators in response to violations being flagged. The quantity of such flags would be quite small, and so it shouldn't be too much of a burden on moderator time.

Comment: Only if they're also exempt from being reopened/undeleted during the same period.

Comment: @KevinB No, I don't think it should be symmetrical. The reason is that deletion makes the post invisible for a lot of users, and then they can no longer participate in the discussion, which doesn't seem right to me. Whether the post is closed/open, or +/-scored, doesn't matter as far as visibility goes.

Comment: That's nothing a screenshot can't fix. Simply bringing something to meta's attention shouldn't require the post to obtain an additional 3-5 votes to put it back where it belongs when all is said and done.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I addressed screenshots as a possibility in the question, as well as issues with that. I'm not sure what you mean by your second sentence. I'm only saying delete votes specifically should be disallowed on questions being discussed. All other actions are fine.

Comment: What if someone brings up a spam or troll post on MSO (e. g. because they are unsure what to do about it)? Should that be kept around?

Comment: @cigien if answers are needed for additional context, they can be screenshotted as well. The default action when something is brought up to meta shouldn't be undelete-reopen just because people can't see it.

Comment: @JeanneDark Well, those should be Spam, or R/A flagged, not deleted anyway. But sure, that would count as an exception.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, I see the confusion. No, I'm not saying that a question that is already deleted should be undeleted. Or that a question should be reopened (not that that has anything to do with visibility). Again, I'm saying *only* additional delete votes should be disallowed when a question is brought up for discussion.

Comment: @JeanneDark I think such a rule could accommodate these cases as exceptions and thus agree with cigien's reasoning. Flagging as R/A, spam, or moderator attention should work the same way as it is now. If a post is in violation of rules, it should not be granted the same immunity "normal" posts get. P.s. But you made a good point which I think should be explicitly stated

Comment: I'm very opposed to a complete freeze. However, yeah, I think deletion should be off-limits for something that is being *actively* discussed, as that one was. Seeing a delete vote come in just as that Meta question was beginning to get traction (i.e., good answers from the people who participated in voting to close it), well, that really pissed me off. Hence the comment. I'm not sure we need an official policy here, but I wouldn't oppose having one. I don't expect the system to help; it can't decide what is under "active" discussion. Moderators can. I intend to. Warnings optional.

Comment: @Kevin Undeletion would also be off-limits, except…you can't undelete something that isn't deleted. So, if we stop deleting questions that are being actively discussed on Meta, then it won't matter whether they can be undeleted. The reason we don't want to delete questions that are under active discussion is because that restricts participation only to users who have 10k+ reputation, which is quite a minority, thus, not only is it completely unfair, but it makes the discussion a lot less fruitful. It's also just rude to delete stuff out from underneath a discussion, like it's a super-downvote.

Comment: Screenshots don't fix anything because you can't edit and improve a screenshot. Often, the best way to say, "I think this should be reopened" is to edit the post. @JeanneDark An exception is made if a moderator thinks the post needs to be immediately deleted, either by seeing a flag on it or by seeing it on Meta. Screenshots and/or copy-pastes can be provided in these (hopefully rare) cases, since editing to salvage it won't be an option. This is, of course, why I think creating a comprehensive policy around something like this a bit of a fool's errand... What happened to common sense?

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, an official rule might be too much to hope for. OTOH, relying on a mod being around for every new Meta post is unreasonable. So I'm thinking of appending to my usual comment something like "Please don't delete this post as it's being actively discussed" (when appropriate). Would that be reasonable? At the moment, the request can be completely ignored, but if I could point to an answer by a mod stating that they take a dim view of this, the comment would be actually effective. If you agree, an answer on this post would be nice, whenever convenient of course.

Comment: I would have no problem with adding that line to your comment. That's half the point of leaving such a comment in the first place. (The other half is, please take your opinions about the question to the Meta discussion, not leave them in comments that someone will have to clean up later.) I like to say both things explicitly when I leave an advisory comment like that. As for the second part... you want me to leave comments *and* answers establishing policy? Man, I am not superhuman. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray What? You're turning down the opportunity to write an answer? I'm shocked ;) But the confirmation in your comment is pretty good; I'll work on redrafting the comment I leave in these situations. Hopefully that'll help somewhat with the issue of marginal quality posts getting insta-deleted when brought up on Meta.

Comment: While I am far too inexperienced to post an answer, or even to evaluate the severity (if any) of this issue, I do find this a very important question. After all, Meta is _how_ we discuss things like deletion practices **in the first place**. If there were a hypothetical trend toward overzealous deletion, critiques of that trend would quickly be deleted _by the trend itself_, and a renormative consensus might never be coherently hashed out.

Comment: Screenshots are not a good substitute. Think of users relying on screen readers to access content. It would prevent them from participating in the discussion. They also prevent users from seeing the history.

Comment: I do agree with this proposal. The meta effect is often mentioned on meta itself when things start to snowball which is fine for quality votes and maybe even close votes but to see a post deleted because of the meta effect... that's pretty much the nuke from orbit going on. We have to contain ourselves and since that conflicts with the freedoms that the site grants you to vote as you see fit, that freedom needs to be put behind a retarder IMO.

Comment: @CodyGray In cases like this a lock is not there to but a lid on discussion, but rather to allow discussion to be had without individuals coming to conclusions by themselves, without community consensus. Kind of the same deal as having a trial in an orderly court rather than in front of an angry mob at the town square. The question being discussed here had a big "close vote war" going on, which is not productive and not helping the OP, nor the site quality. This could have been prevented with a lock. And at some extent the lock also prevents "the meta effect".

Comment: So a look seems like an entirely good thing, assuming that the moderator(s) are actively monitoring the discussion and remembering to unlock it once something resembling a consensus has been reached.

Comment: @Lundin As mentioned elsewhere, locking the question is taking the side of the close voters, only worse, marginally better than the post being outright deleted. OP cannot get new answers, comments, votes, bounties, edits and even views can be severely diminished since it is excluded from the HNQ list, and other lists. By the time it gets unlocked, if that even happens, interest in the question is likely to be lost.

Comment: @user000001 And not locking it is taking the side of those who wish to see it open... What's important here is to not throw some unsuspecting, possibly new user under the meta bus, overflowing their question with all manner of votes, edits and comments. It's very unpleasant to be on the receiving side of that.

Comment: @Lundin: Not really, if not locked, it can still be downvoted/closed/deleted/flagged etc

Comment: @CodyGray What if someone asks on Meta about an already deleted question?

Comment: @TylerH I mentioned that in a [previous comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408248/should-posts-that-are-actively-being-discussed-on-meta-be-temporarily-exempt-fro#comment847553_408248), as well as comments on some answers. If a post is already deleted, I'm not suggesting that it be undeleted for the discussion. I'm not sure if one of Cody's comments suggests otherwise, I'm just pointing out that that's not part of my proposal.

Comment: Suggesting that screenshots aren't adequate implies that deleted questions that are being discussed should be undeleted, because "the community can't see them to have an opinion".

Comment: @KevinB which is ridiculous because I have opinions on all deleted questions!

Comment: Well, have you asked me what's my opinion on them? Keep them deleted. If there's a question I want to ask but it's deleted, I would just ask it. I don't have time to search something that was not high quality enough to be kept publicly available, so I prefer to create it myself.

Comment: This discussion came up again on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411306/request-for-clarification-on-moderation-policy-regarding-deletion-of-so-question), requesting an official stance on this suggested policy.

Answer (score 30):

I never really thought of it as a "rule" that needs to be "enforced", but perhaps there are some people who are a bit more delete-eager than I am in these cases.

Ultimately, the moderators can do what they like/say what they like in this regard.  They're the ones that deal with the flags about this kind of question anyway, and I'm reading Cody's remark here more as him putting his foot **down** as opposed to now saying in a blanket fashion that "all questions being discussed on Meta are exempt from deletion".

Because we've discussed deleted questions here before without batting an eye.

I lean towards this being a reaction to the amount of eagerness that everyone has in trying to moderate *this* question, and I would firmly disagree with this being a new "rule".  This feels pretty exceptional; this doesn't happen often enough for us to really need to deal with this at such a level, and the mod team should be equipped to deal with this.

(If they're short-staffed, maybe they could use another election to get some more willing participants, idk)

Comment: Yes, of course Cody was only referring to the specific question. I'm asking if this should be made a general rule. At the moment, there's no restriction on casting delete votes, so a flag would likely be declined. Also, I'm not referring to posts on Main that are already deleted, in case that was confusing.

Comment: @cigien: I think my main point stands, then.  Doesn't make a whole lot of sense to.  I'm not really a fan of a ton of rules or policies that exist if this sort of thing only happens once in a blue moon.

Comment: It doesn't really happen only once in a blue moon. It happens regularly that posts being discussed on meta just vanishes.. sometimes a moderator un-deletes them and locks them so us mere mortals can see the post.

Comment: @Makoto - I think we already have a Talmud-sized rule codex, written and unwritten - one more won't hurt as much :) Although I see the point you make here.

Comment: @Scratte:  The  irregularity I speak of is the one where there's an obvious close/reopen war such that moderators are pinged about it *to the degree* that they would threaten users with suspension should the war continue.  I said before that we can talk about deleted questions here all the time without *that* much of an issue, since 10k+ users can take screenshots of the contentious content.  The exceptional part is the extreme stance.

Comment: IIUC, your answer has 2 main points. 1) -This is exceptional.- I don't have concrete figures, but based on personal experience, it's not at all uncommon for linked posts to be deleted. 2) -mods are equipped to handle this.- I don't follow: what are mods supposed to do? Unless they post a comment *beforehand* like Cody did, there's no rule/warning against deleting linked content. I fail to see what mods can do if a post gets deleted. (Also, I want to stress, this *does not* include posts that are already deleted; I'm definitely not suggesting that they be undeleted so as to be visible.)

Comment: @cigien:  In my anecdotal experience, it is *vanishingly rare* for a diamond mod to involve themselves with a deleted question like this *unless* there's an explicit moderation-related reason to.  I would imagine that the fact that there's a delete war would be the tipping point, which is why it's exceptional - that doesn't happen all the time.  Additionally, mods *are* equipped to handle this.  Cody just did in the way I would expect a mod to deal with this kind of chatter - a clear warning shot across the bow to all active parties.

Comment: @cigien:  Fundamentally speaking, though, moderators prefer to leave the kind of routine moderation tasks to the community, which would include deletion.  If the content is contentious, then sure, that's a reason for a mod to get involved.  But the number of questions I see that are discussed on Meta that are deleted usually *stay* deleted, as the exercise when discussing the question is to both prove its worth/topicality on the site, *and* then decide that it's worth reopening/undeleting.

Comment: @cigien: This is why I say it's exceptional.  Mods don't just *do* this all the time.  I don't disagree that questions are deleted a lot - maybe more than I'd like them to be - but this kind of action from a moderator is *rare* indeed.

Comment: The mod action that you're referring to needs to happen *before* the post is deleted, and mods aren't always looking at Meta. It would be simpler to just include the bit about deletion in the usual, "this question is being discussed ..." comment. I'm with you about exceptional cases, but I don't see why this goes against that. Mods would have no reason to get involved unless the rule is violated. Also, I'm sure you read the question thoroughly, but based on the phrasing in your answer, I feel I should clarify that the exemption on deletion is meant to be *temporary*.

Comment: @cigien:  You place too much emphasis on the fact that the post is deleted.  **This doesn't really matter.**  Questions which are deleted are a dime a dozen and we discuss them here *all* the time.  The mod stepping in to demand a stop to a reopen war is *exceptional* and thus I would be very hesitant to suggest that this become some *policy* that always gets invoked in this scenario since **it doesn't happen often enough for us to care about it**!

Comment: Ok, I think I see your POV. I would say that whether a post is deleted matters very much to <10k users, because it pretty much prevents them from participating in the discussion. Also, I'm really now unsure if you've understood my request. You mention reopen wars, and that has nothing to do with my request; close and reopen votes can be cast. You also mention questions that are already deleted; also not part of my request. Also, mods *wouldn't* have to step in very often. Once the few users who violate the rule (if implemented) are warned, it's unlikely to happen again.

Comment: We're still ships passing in the night @cigien.  I'm going to spell it out clearly:  1)  Mods don't get involved in deleted posts unless there's a clear and concise moderation reason to do so.  A question that is *only* being discussed (not actioned or resolved) on Meta is normally ***not*** such a reason.  2)  < 10K users can participate in discussions on deleted posts because 10k+ users **post pictures of the deleted question**.  3)  The reason that I mention a reopen war is that this is the only ***logical*** reason why a mod would be bothered.

Comment: Yes, clearly we're not understanding each other at some level. It's probably my fault for being unclear, though I'm not sure how I can clarify things any further. Thanks for the feedback though, I do appreciate it. BTW, I agree that point 2) from your previous comment does mitigate the concerns I raised, as I alluded to in my question. It's not ideal, but if this rule is not implemented, that's not a terrible workaround.

Comment: While I'm in near complete agreement with this answer, I think Makoto significantly underestimates the frequency with which this happens. And by "this", I mean that a borderline question is brought up on Meta to discuss its closure, some members of the community decide that they hate the Q, so they cast delete votes on it as if they were "super-downvotes", thus preventing most people from reasonably participating in the Meta discussion and short-circuiting the whole idea of community-led discussion/moderation. I see it *far* too often. It's rare a Q is brought up on Meta, ofc, but when it is…

Comment: @CodyGray:  That might get to the pet peeve that I think we share about eager deletion of content.  I don't normally see it pop up as an *issue* such that some diamond mod has to comment to threaten parties about this (in fact I think this is the first time I've seen it), but I would yield to your superior experience in this matter.

Comment: "I lean towards this being a reaction to the amount of eagerness that everyone has in trying to moderate this question" I would lean towards this being an **very strong overreaction** about people moderating questions they find.

Comment: @CodyGray Then you should start suspending people who upvote borderline questions as a result of seeing them on Meta. That Meta effect is even more well known than deletion. You can't make this a one-way street against people who want to moderate a particular piece of content; you have to eliminate *all* the effects of people's biases.

Comment: Upvoting doesn't have consequences of limiting further viewing or involvement with the post. Neither does downvoting. So both can be done at will. Deletion is a larger weapon, so needs to be handled with vastly more care. This seems self-evident, which is why I didn't take time to explain it all in the comment. It's not a "one-way street" against anyone. If you want that content deleted, you should argue for that on the Meta question, just like the people who have opposing opinions. What you should *not* be entitled to do is delete the question, thus eclipsing debate. @jpmc26

Comment: @CodyGray You're right. Upvoting has a much worse consequence: granting user privileges. The system is already heavily biased towards upvoting; it doesn't need even more. Sitting around and doing absolutely nothing while bad content is rewarded is not a viable solution to the problem of limited visibility.

Comment: No one has ever argued in favor of "sitting around and doing absolutely nothing". The choice isn't binary. It isn't either delete it or do nothing. There are zillions of options, including downvoting, editing, and making your case on Meta. I strongly discourage *anyone* from sitting around and doing absolutely nothing in absolutely any case, much less when bad content is being rewarded. But, of course, this begs the question of whether what we're discussing was bad content, and whether it was *irredeemable* bad content, which would be the only grounds for deletion. Empirically, it wasn't.

Comment: @CodyGray "*Upvoting doesn't have consequences of limiting further viewing or involvement with the post. Neither does downvoting*" A post at -3 (or is it -4?) will stop showing up on the questions list; you'll have to filter/search for it directly to see it. So in a sense, downvoting *does* limit further viewing and involvement with the post, by design. It also can indirectly limit it by working to trigger the Roomba, depending on other factors that the Roomba takes into account.

Comment: Deleting something on meta doesn't prevent people who can undo it from seeing it either. Locking it keeps it visible for everyone

Answer (score 14):

It sounds as though your concern is not actually with the deletion, but the viewing.

> This means a substantial number of users, (i.e. <10k rep), can no longer fully participate in the discussion.

Some cleaner options than simply freezing deletion, all of which unfortunately would require some complexity:

- allowing the deleted question to be viewed after deletion for a certain period of time by anyone using a direct link
- "snapshotting" the initial state (and linking to that in the meta)

  - this also solves issues of details changing after the question being asked
  - one could even dream of an anonymized version of this, where users are replaced by colors or animals

Comment: There *are* other concerns with quick deletion, but you're right, viewing is definitely a big one, and the one I focus on in the question. Your suggested fixes seem mostly reasonable, and would help with the issue, but they would require dev time, and I'm not *too* optimistic about that happening. If dev time were to be invested, I think a delete-only-lock would be quite clean, and directly address the issue. Minor point: why the anonymized version that you mentioned at the end? What would the purpose of that be?

Comment: @cigien - I guess the latter is to steer the voting/discussion towards the issues with the post rather than the users behind it. Posting from an anonymous account seems to be frowned upon as we observed during one of the regex debacles, so the *system* anonymizing (pseudo) the posts could potentially help. That said, I do agree it requires dev time (and from a rough estimate a significant amount) so it's basically inactionable.

Comment: @OlegValter Oh, I see. I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me, but you're absolutely right. In most, if not all cases, it's the content under discussion, not the users, so anonymizing makes a lot of sense indeed.

Comment: I've been giving this a lot of thought recently, for reasons that should be obvious if you read Meta, and I think that freezing deletion is really the best and simplest option. Allowing viewing or snapshotting of the deleted question is a major change to the system, and probably not a reasonable use of developer time. A simpler way to do this would just be to require that the Meta question include the full text of the question from main. But this, like allowing viewing, doesn't solve the concern I have regarding the need to maintain the ability to vote and edit.

Comment: "_details changing after the question being asked_" ... snapshots already exist and you can link directly to them: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/408248/2. I like this idea. Maybe if we allowed users to view revisions even after the question has been deleted it would solve all the problems. You can't interact with a revision already, so there's no extra work involved in disabling voting, etc.

Comment: Maybe we should let 10k users search deleted posts and normal users see deleted posts with the direct link.

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely not.

Moderators already have a tool to prevent question deletion: it's called a lock. If a question is so controversial that it needs extensive Meta discussion, it involves strongly held opinions on both sides, and moderators wish to prevent action until a resolution can be determined, then the lock is the appropriate solution.

Leaving a question undeleted but still allowing interaction is picking a side in the disagreement: it's favoring the question, allowing it to continue garnering upvotes (which heavily outweigh downvotes in terms of reputation) and allowing continued comments and making it easier to reopen and post answers. All you're doing is taking away moderation tools from users, furthering this nonsense prejudice against people who wish to moderate content on its merits. All this policy will do is **fuel** frustration and conflict.

Furthermore, this is clearly open to abuse. Anyone can start a discussion on Meta. This policy becomes an easy way to stave off deletion and manufacture controversy for any question that really ought to be moderated.

Comment: Generally, "staving off deletion" brings very few benefits to the asker. The "abuse window" seem very, very small, IMO. My main take on allowing questions to be deleted quickly (or locking them otherwise), is that it "protects" users from further downvotes on poor questions. Yes, in theory questions _could_ be edited and salvaged. But that happens rarely, while the vote pile-on happens frequently.

Comment: "Furthermore, this is clearly open to abuse. Anyone can start a discussion on Meta." Reminds me of bounties. It's very frustrating to come across a question that cannot be moderated because it has just the minimum bounty on it. It's hard to stay objective in this case – stalking a question until it's moderatable again doesn't help with a neutral attitude, and abandoning it just goes the other direction.

Comment: @yivi: Agreed, that's why I proposed an alternate method for protecting the OP of the question from the downvotes, without the need for a speedy deletion, in [my answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408301).

Comment: @user000001 I saw you answer. I think it's thoroughly wrong, but other users already commented there to that effect explaining its shortcomings.

Comment: I agree that a lock is appropriate to use, for a day or two while the matter is discussed at meta. "Delete wars" isn't the only problem, "Close wars" are just as bad. Also locking prevents "the meta effect" at some extent.

Comment: @yivi I'm envisioning a question that has roughly equal numbers of advocates on each side, both with very strongly held opinions. That seems like the most likely candidate where this would even be an issue. In such cases, the score would be near zero, but the question would still garner net positive reputation.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There should be a new type of lock: delete vote lock, which mods could apply temporarily (e.g. 48hs) in cases where it's really needed (which would not be always).

This would allow to use this rule properly, allow regular interaction with the question that a lot of times is needed (edits, comments, CV/RO votes, regular votes) without threats and with much less discussion and aggravation.

Comment: This could work, except that it requires a mod to actually see the post on meta, and apply the lock in time. It's not uncommon for someone to post a meta linking to something on main, the post on main gets deleted, and then the post on meta is deleted (often by the OP of the meta post) all in very short order. Even if this feature were to be implemented (which is highly unlikely given that it's not a high priority issue), it would be preferable IMO to have a policy in place, similar to how the "one delete/undelete per user" issue was resolved.

Comment: @cigien it can probably be solved by a mod-only bot (since I bear no confidence in SE being able to do anything more complex than something utterly trivial due to the latest issues). That said, yeah, having a policy would at least allow consistent handling of the matter.

Comment: It would require mod intervention only on specific cases, and for that we have flags. The "policy" also needs mods intervention, because otherwise you have simply depends on users having read the "policy" and remember it. With a temporary lock that it's put in place when needed, you have less friction all around, less vague threats and informal policy.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be an exceptionally rare question that is both under discussion on Meta and also not somehow on the borders of acceptability. Putting a lock on a question under discussion assumes that a significant share of these questions should be treated as acceptable, and I haven't seen evidence that this is the case. Maybe someone can do the research to see how many of these questions ultimately are judged to be acceptable and should remain available to the general public, but I suspect it's a pretty rare situation.

Meanwhile it's a big technological request for a situation that already has workarounds. A 10k+ member can always screenshot the question if the deletion really is a big mistake and worthy of continued discussion, but locking up the standard review process because someone (often the author) initiated a Meta discussion would introduce a pretty big hole in the moderation system; a hole that would be ripe for abuse by bad actors.

I think we need to optimize for the 99.9% of cases and then lean on the advanced moderation tools available to trusted users (10k+, diamond mods, etc) to handle the unusual cases.

#### Best Case Scenario

An experienced user asks a question on the main site about a technology they are not familiar with, thus failing to provide some standard details. There's a decent question buried in there, but due to the lack of clarity many readers misunderstand the question and vote to close thinking that it lacks sufficient detail.

The user asks about it one meta and gets some good advice. The user then goes to clean up the question, but the meta effect has drawn a lot of attention to the question and it continues to get downvotes and a few trigger-happy users vote to delete.

##### Current Solutions:

A diamond mod intervenes and warns off the delete-voters.

The question is eventually edited, re-tagged and the end result is a positive score and a net-gain in reputation.

##### Proposed Solutions: (*including some of those offered up by in answers*)

- **Auto-lock** The existence of a link to the post on the main site triggers.

  **Problems**

  - Many users link to posts for many reasons, not all of which include "I think this post should remain open". Sometimes it's to report incidences of voting fraud or to report spam.
  - Bad actors, such as spammers, could easily create Meta posts in an effort to circumvent moderation. This would necessitate either constant intervention by diamond mods or complicated exceptions for spam flags, etc.
- **Manual Locks** Diamond mods or users with sufficient rep (whatever you want here) can apply manual locks

  **Problems**

  - If we're saying only diamond mods should have this ability, then why aren't the diamond mods asking for this? And can you imagine the amount of whining from users who *don't* get this lock applied to their question? Essentially we'd be asking diamond mods to review every single post on meta asking why some poorly written or off-topic question is getting negative attention and then make a decision to apply or not-apply the lock, which then sets off a whole other discussion about why the mods did or didn't apply the lock.
  - If we're saying anyone with sufficient rep can apply this lock, then who? And can the lock by un-applied? How do we prevent users from abusing it? What's the criteria we use to judge whether abuse has occurred? Are there exceptions for post authors? Should users with sufficient rep vote to lock the post? We have enough arguments about existing moderation tools. This new moderation tool would be no different.

#### Worst Case Scenarios

- A spammer realizes they can create bots that post to SO main site and then a few seconds later (or in response to the first downvote) post a question on meta asking how they can improve their question.
- A high-rep user who, in their own eyes, can do no wrong posts a question and is offended that it's not received as the genius question it is. They manipulate the moderation tools to lock the question down so that it can't be closed because more time will clearly reveal it to be God's gift to humanity.
- A new user asks an off-topic question. It gets some negative attention on the main site so they open a meta post to ask why it's off-topic. Other new users (and some experienced users opposed to moderation in general) join the meta discussion and the question hangs around for days attracting opinionated answers and generally wasting time with a question that will, ultimately, be closed.

#### We need some evidence

Of course, all of the above might be worth the hassle if there was actually some evidence that there are a significant number of questions that need this lock to prevent the injustice of closure and downvotes on perfectly acceptable questions that are in no need of editing, cleaning and tweaking. I doubt that there are many questions like this, but I am very open to being proven wrong.

However, such evidence needs to be provided **before** significant changes to the existing moderation tools are warranted. Everyone wants to change the moderation tools to better reflect their opinions on how the site should be run or to better benefit themselves. Carefully curated evidence is the best way to **prove** that an issue exists beyond opinion, speculation and preference.

So far I've seen only one example (the one presented by the OP) and the situation seems to have worked out very well for the original question. It's sitting with +10 (and a rep gain of about 276, if I'm doing my math correctly) and was only closed as a duplicate (which isn't a bad sort of closure). I just don't see the problem.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it only takes 3 10K users on meta that think that 99.9% of questions should be deleted (like you seem to), and then virtually every meta-effect question gets deleted, even though the rest of the viewers  (N-3) don't believe that all these questions should be deleted.

Comment: @user000001 - That's a bit unfair. I don't think that most questions should be deleted and I rarely vote like that myself. However, asking to disable the ability to delete a question because someone posted on Meta... that's a BIG change to our moderation system. We'd need some pretty strong evidence that such a change is warranted, not to mention all the complexity required to prevent abuse. I'd just like to see _some_ evidence that this is actually warranted on such a broad scale. We need more than one example question.

Comment: per your update... we already have manual locks, have had them for quite a long time. Mods just seem to be against using them for anything other than old questions that *should* be deleted. High rep users can apply locks too, but only to prevent new users from answering, it doesn't prevent anything else.

Comment: @KevinB - Yes, I'm aware. In the context of this post, either a new lock has been proposed or a broader usage for existing locks. My criticism applies equally well to either case. (In fact, quite a bit screen ink has been [spilled over existing locks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250099/211627), so there's good precedent for how controversial these locks can be)

Comment: 1) The proposal is *temporary* exexmption from deletion, not permanent. 2) No *technological/system* fix is being proposed, of any magnitude. 3) Locking is too heavy handed. This has been covered in numerous places, so I won't get into the details of it here. 4) Your worst case scenarios don't sound particularly problematic, and are not exacerbated by this proposal. The spammer example is definitely a non-issue, I can guarantee that. A spammer who tries the stunt of linking to a spam post on Meta is going to get nuked almost immediately, so don't worry at all about that.

Comment: 5) This is the important one. I agree I haven't given a curated list of examples. I honestly didn't think anyone would need convincing that low quality posts linked on Meta get deleted faster than they would otherwise. For the specific example, your analysis in the last para is misleading. The score on Main was negative when the Meta was posted, and the post *did* get a delete vote soon after. If not for the comment from the mod, it's entirely possible, if not likely, that the post would have been deleted, and then it would never have reached the score, and condition it is in now.

Comment: @cigien - To your last point, I don't think my last para was misleading precisely because the question *did* get a comment from a diamond mod which was sufficient. The only example we have to work with at the moment shows that the existing system works fine. We would need other examples of where the existing system has failed before a change is warranted.

Comment: Also, @cigien, I'm responding both to your original question and some of the other answers. Sorry if that wasn't clear... I'm aware that you haven't proposed locking all moderation, but I wanted to provide a response to those that have as part of the larger discussion.

Comment: 1) Yes, the mod comment did work here, but that means we'd be relying on mods to be active enough to see all these cases? I don't think that's reasonable, and so I think a policy would be preferable. Still, the mod has confirmed that they're fine with users essentially saying what the mod comment said (minus the "Moderator" bit obviously ;)), so I'm going to do that from now on. 2) Ah, thanks for clarifying, and editing the answer. I suspected that the locking bit wasn't addressed directly at my question. I see why you mention it though, many users have offered up that alternative.

Comment: @cigien - I don't have stats on this, but I recall a conversation that many spam posts generate many more downvotes than spam flags. Many users aren't aware of the spam flag, but they know how to downvote. Allowing high-rep users to delete those messages ASAP, with or without spam flags, is an important part of moderation. Of course, this might be worth giving up if a lot of decent questions get deleted during that 24 hour window you are proposing which would otherwise not get deleted, but we just don't have numbers on that and no one seems to have the appetite to find those numbers.

Comment: The discussion on spam is bit tangential, but basically, there's no potential for abuse here with regards to spam. Yes, some people downvote/delete instead of flagging, but it's not a big deal; flagging is the right approach for spam, but it's fine either way. And even if someone delete votes a spam post linked from, or discussed on Meta, I can guarantee that they won't get into any trouble for that. Of course, I don't have any authority to make that claim, but feel free to quote me on this for what that's worth. TL;DR treat spam as you would otherwise; it being linked on Meta is irrelevant.

Answer (score -8):

Using my privileged position of a sub 10ker and the one that "saved" that question I have an opinion on this. But here's the tl'dr:

#### I just don't care if it's deleted

I really don't. I edited the question just to teach users how to use their powers instead of complaining to meta (flexing the edit privilege), making a point on how users that should know better act. Apparently that message is lost on more drama, that I find totally unwarranted. There's nothing special about either the question or the answers. In fact (takes soap box) is just a indication of how bad the trend has been in terms of the content quality. They not only stopped reading book, or the documentation, or their code, or the tutorial, but actually stopped knowing that they don't know.

Outside of that, I haven't seen a question on meta that was deleted that I didn't agree with the deletion or at least really didn't care that it was deleted, and seeing the screenshot I never missed much (most of the time was morbid curiosity). I don't see any benefit to such policy and no benefit of making the question available for the rest of the public. My point on edits was lost anyways, so whatevers.

Comment: _I just don't care if it's deleted_ ---> What if someone else cares? What if someone wants it to be undeleted so that they can make their point, and they think that the post is useful? Just because you don't care doesn't mean someone else doesn't care.

Comment: @10Rep Agreed.  While (I imagine) a mod might often have to make a judgement call in good faith, the landscape changes entirely on _Meta_.  After all, Meta is where we discuss such moderation (and deletion) practices _in the first place_.

Comment: Exactly what @10Rep said. Someone obviously cared enough about it to make a Meta question, and at least one other person cared enough to post an answer on that Meta question, so, frankly, I just don't care if Braiam doesn't care.

Comment: @10Rep you aren't the target of the policy: you aren't someone that would actually act upon the question to "save" it in a way that would have been prevented by deletion. **I did**, and not the moderator that posted the comment, nor the asker of the meta question, nor any of the answeres, nor commenters. **I did**. None of their interactions would have been prevented by deletion and posterior undeletion.

Answer (score -26):

I totally agree with the proposal, but I would make it more general:

Not only delete, but also downvote, close and flag (except for spam) options should be disabled on the question and the answers, if there is a "this is being discussed on meta" comment under the question.

To prevent abuse, there should be manual suspension of users that post such comments when the linked meta question isn't about the question with the comment.

It would probably be a good idea to have the comment added automatically too, in case nobody adds it manually.

Edit:

@Hoppeduppeanut made a good point about meta posts being potentially linked for different reasons, without the meta post being about the SO post. So the criteria for enabling the protection should check that the link goes both ways: The meta post (directly or in an answer/comment) should link to the SO post, **and** there should be a "This is being discussed on meta" comment on the SO post, that links to the same meta post.

Comment: While I'm unqualified to _state_ it, I do _suspect_ this would defeat the purpose. I think the goal is to give SO the time to hash out important Meta questions, retrieve any "babies from the bathwater", and possibly reach a more nuanced consensus; all via a conversation that has time to eventually develop productively. Indeed, important questions often entail high stakes with attendant controversy, so important conversations often take longer to stabilize and flesh out. Since downvotes (and flags?) are themselves part of that conversation, disabling them might also harm the conversation.

Comment: Big -1, this completely disregards the fact that users can link to meta posts in comments for reasons other than to make sure a discussed post doesn't get deleted, such as examples for burnination/retag requests, and general questions about a specific post. These posts would be caught up by this automatic commenting and have these interactions blocked. Besides that, [we already have post locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/393532) which prevent all these interactions (except for flagging), and are applied by mods when there is *actually* an issue that warrants such a lock.

Comment: @Greg: Yes you have a point, on the other hand the problem is that when something is linked from meta it gets an enormous number of views from people with close/delete/downvote  privilege, so the question gets hit hard and the OP risks getting banned. See also [What is the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut: Locks are not sufficient, because a) they require an actual moderator to get involved, so it isn't scalable and b) They also block positive actions such as new answers, upvotes, featuring in HNQ, reopening, undeleting, editing, etc. You do have a point about meta posts being linked for other reasons, so I will make an edit on my answer to address that.

Comment: On principle, I refuse to disable downvoting without also disabling upvoting. And if we disable voting, then we're getting *very* close to an outright lock, which I'm really not comfortable with. I actually think allowing voting is useful: it gives a way for people to express their opinion about the post *without* having to vote to delete it (which risks removing it from view entirely to a large segment of users), and it also gives a lower-friction way for people to express their opinion (i.e., doesn't require drafting a Meta answer, which many people don't have time for or don't want to do).

Comment: Regarding flags, I'm not too worried about that. The worst case is it creates a couple of additional flags for mods to review and dismiss. And, honestly, I don't like the idea of disabling flagging on *anything*. Flags need to always be there as an escape hatch. Since they're reviewed by human moderators, there is little risk in the option being available. So, I really like where you're going with wanting to make this more general, but I think you are going a bit in the wrong direction, ending up with many of the disadvantages that I seek to avoid.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes you are probably right about the downvoting, but it would probably be a good idea to exempt the post from the question-ban algorithm.

Comment: @user000001 Thanks for the info! I had actually suspected that Meta, as a setting, might induce sampling bias in who responds (and with what disposition). That said, I feel a misguided downvote is not as epistemically destructive as a misguided closing/deletion. While downvotes might _sway_ the conversation, so might a scathing counterpoint (if not as efficiently as the psychological priming effect of a negative tally). By contrast, (I think) bad closings _halt_ the conversation before it matures, and deletions render it _invisible_. A good point might survive the former, but not the latter!

Comment: The way I look at it is, if the post is truly unsalvageable, then it will be eventually deleted, and the downvotes essentially won't matter. (A single bad question isn't going to get you question-banned.) If the post can be salvaged, then it will ultimately end up good enough to earn upvotes, and those will outweigh the downvotes. So, yeah, it's not ideal; this goes back to an issue we've known and discussed many times before, which is basically just a special case of the old adage that you only get one chance to make a good first impression. But we do our best to allow redemption.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to at least give a reason why you would disable only negative interactions? This seems to unfairly skew the rating/moderation of content. Upvoting is *already* much more rewarding than downvoting, and close voting is easily reversible if done out of malice/spite/misconception – what is the benefit of only allowing positive interactions?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Can't make the edit right now (in a meeting), but in short the purpose is to avoid the meta-effect, without punishing the question's OP, so to allow positive, but not negative.

Comment: @user000001 Yet the meta effect is also for positive interactions. I've seen absolute SO-turds accumulate hundreds of rep because they were posted on meta. Even if they can be deleted later on to wipe that rep, should people stalk these posts forever to ensure they stay deleted?

Comment: Manual suspension won't work for bad actors. Spammers would love to keep their posts around a bit longer by automatically opening a meta post to "ask" if their question is "ok", then having their question hang around for a long time while mods scramble to build enough "consensus" to close the meta post. Diamond mods would likely be swamped within hours. There's just too much complexity to this approach, and not enough evidence that the underlying situation is common. Given some compelling ***evidence***, I would change my mind. Without that evidence, it's a non-starter.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica: i specifically excluded spam flags from the lock, I think 5 such flags are enough for the post to be deleted and the user to be marked as a spammer. As for the evidence, I can't start looking though all meta effect questions to see how many are deleted, but from personal experience it's quite frequent.