# Can this question about Minecraft be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm working on answering questions in the [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag, and I found this one ([How would I increase the max build limit in minecraft?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922901/how-would-i-increase-the-max-build-limit-in-minecraft)), which was closed as "needing focus".

I submitted an edit that was approved.

Now, I believe the question is clearer and I believe it's fine. But, my request for reopening it has been declined in review.

I would like to know why. It seems it's not focused, but the question doesn't talk about multiple issues any longer, but only one: "building up to 256 blocks".

Comment: Looks like some people may wish to revisit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408248/should-posts-that-are-actively-being-discussed-on-meta-be-temporarily-exempt-fro#comment847672_408249

Comment: Both the Stack Overflow question and this meta question look reasonable to me - I was addressing those who voted to delete the question under discussion right after this meta question was posted.

Comment: I think the comment by @CertainPerformance was addressing those who voted to delete the question. I just voted to undelete (in the spirit of Meta and the linked comment). One more such should bring it back.

Comment: Note that, of the 5 'opportunities' to vote to reopen the question (2 in suggested edit review and 3 in the reopen queue), only one ("Approve and Reopen" in the edit review) actually voted to reopen. I was one of the "leave closed" voters, and I stand by that decision. The question is, IMHO, rather vague, and lacks both focus and detail.

Comment: Yes there isn't any code in the question, so I understand that some people can think it need more focus. But this question doesn't ask to fix code. I add a link of possible fix that doesn't work to be more precise. So, why do you think it need more details ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the question asks how to configure a game, right? How is that a programming problem? The answers are also terrible: One is half a comment and half completely wrong. The other one is a link to a off-site resource.

Comment: The game can be edited with Java programming, with datapack and with config. So, such as config doesn't work, he are trying to check if it can do it on the server but with code (to force it)

Comment: @Elikill58: But the question doesn't read as if op is writing code themselves. Recommending code from somewhere else or installing datapacks is, imho, both off-topic

Comment: If it really an offtopic, why it's close as not focused instead of offtopic ? Because i more understand offtopic flag. If it's real one, where should be moved ?

Comment: Perhaps it should have been closed as *About general computing hardware and software* but once it is closed we generally don't reopen it just to close it again with a different reason. Looks like it potentially could work on [arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-data-packs)

Comment: @Elikill58 - A limitation of the close system is only one close reason will be displayed despite multiple reasons being selected by the community.  Why are you putting so much effort into a question that is clearly out of scope at Stack Overflow? A question that was abandoned over a year ago by its author?

Comment: The Question has been "Viewed 31k times". So it's clearly of interest to a lot of people.

Comment: @Scratte How is that particularly relevant or interesting? That a question is hit often  is supposed to bolster what argument?

Comment: It doesn't seem clearly out of scope for Stack Overflow to everyone, so the fact that a lot of people want to know the same thing, weighs in for me.

Comment: It's either on-topic or not. That it's popular has nothing to do with topicality, @Scratte. It's not particularly surprising that a question about a very popular game is popular itself. I'm not saying is off-topic (nor the opposite), but please do not muddy the waters by bringing arguments to the mix that are really orthogonal to the issue being discussed. The question could have 3 views, and still be on-topic, and the opposite is equally true.

Comment: @Scratte - It doesn’t have the voting activity that 31k views should have.  Just because it’s being found by a search engine search results and being viewed doesn’t mean it’s within scope

Comment: Also because it was closed so people can't vote for it ?

Comment: @Elikill58 Being closed doesn't make a question ineligible to receive votes.

Comment: @Elikill58 - No; 31,000 unique hits, assuming 20% can actually upvote the question, very few of those unique hits choose upvote the question.  You received more downvotes by the way. If that question had dozens of votes in both directions then it might be worth molding into a on topic question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is fine to ask questions about an API used by a game. However, such questions should be about a specific problem, ideally with a piece of code (minimal complete example) which demonstrates the problem. It would be okay to ask:

> The bottleneck I'm reaching here though is the max height limit that Minecraft has. I tried this:
> `// Java code here!`
> But it gives me... instead of...
>
> I want to increase the max Y value...

Referring to some random forum post isn't helpful. This question was correctly closed as too broad from the start and has not been improved sufficiently. It could also have been closed as "questions asking for debug help..."

Disclaimer: I may be wrong though since I don't know the topic. If someone with domain knowledge in Java and Minecraft understands what is asked without further details provided, then the question should be re-opened. Ideally someone with gold badge in [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) should make the call here, but the tag might have too low traffic for such users to appear. Lacking gold badgers, maybe some of the top users of the tag could chime in.

Comment: If it's only about "is the question understandable?", even if i'm not gold badge in this tag, it's easy to understand for minecraft players. "The tag might have too low trafic" but this question have been bumped two times so even if the tag isn't active, this question seems interesting for people

Comment: @Elikill58 It's not sufficient that the *goal* is understandable. The *specific problem* must be understandable, and it must be on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

> Can this question about Minecraft be reopened?

No.

> I would like to know why.

Just because a question can be answered by programming, **does not inherently make the question programming-related**. To paraphrase one of /r/programming's rules (which IMO should be officially adopted and codified here):

> Just because it has a computer in it doesn't make it programming. If there is no code in your question, it probably doesn't belong here.

As the question is about a videogame, it would be a far more appropriate fit for arqade.se. But it is absolutely, positively not on topic on Stack Overflow.

Please don't polish turds. Flush them.

Comment: "If there is no code in your question, it probably doesn't belong here". Except some of us prefer How-To Questions.. and are not fans of debugging ones.

Comment: Probably strikes me as "likely", which seems to indicate that it is more likely to not belong than to belong.

Comment: @Scratte Which is exactly the truth.

Comment: But using programming can fix the issue, because we can edit the server thanks to spigot's one. That's why original author used `java` tag and why I think it's on-topic.

Comment: I think we have very different views of what is useful. I find botched code attempt Questions to be pretty useless in general. Every Answer is tailored to it and I want to know how to do something, not how to fix someone else's specific code snippet.

Comment: My view is: it isn't obviously a programming question as written. It'd be possible to write a programming question about a similar issue. The best thing might be if this question were deleted and a thus a better, more on-topic question could be asked instead (and not closed as a duplicate)

Comment: @Elikill58 You can fix nearly any computer issue using programming. That doesn't make most computer questions programming questions. Very many answers on Server Fault contain some code, even though the questions are about configuring servers and not about programming, like this one.

Comment: That "rule" is already codified on the help center/on topic page "a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**". People just conveniently leave it out when quoting the page.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to know the limit between game, software or main stackoverflow site. So, such as it's about a game it should be on gaming ? But it's on spigot srv that is in java, it's here ? It's one of the most difficult thing to understand, such as people who have issue with apache website and ask them on SO instead of software

Comment: @IanKemp Just to be thorough: coding and mod/ game development questions *generally [aren't on topic on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*. Please don't suggest that they get asked there. If you want to give an alternative, point to [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead.