# What is the limit of wording changes in post edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

I've posted a few questions here on meta and often people with 2k+ rep have edited my post.

On one question ([Can this question about Minecraft be reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411302)), the title started as *"Why this question isn't reopened"*, it was then changed to *"Why was this question kept closed after being focused?"* and currently it's *"Can this question about Minecraft be reopened?"*, which doesn't have the same meaning.

At the beginning I was just *looking for an explanation*, and at the end it's become a *reopening request*.

The same goes with things like *"P.S."* ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/411138/3)) or *"Update"*. I already saw a question where an edit removed those lines.

What is the limit of an edit? What should be removed/ edited/ etc.?

Comment: Roll back changes you don't want, and you could `@` the editor (even though editor names don't autocomplete). (Maybe your post is not so clear if edits are changing the meaning of parts.) "Update"s don't belong in posts, write the best presentation as of edit time. PS Please research before considering posting a question. [help] SO/SE search is literal & buggy, google with 'site:' to find Qs&As.

Comment: Thanks for tips ! For research, yes i didn't find something that help me, even on Se. That's why I ask this one.

Comment: There is no clear phrasing of your question in your post body or title. "the limit of an edit" doesn't mean anything. We have to guess from overall. So how can you expect to successfully search? (Rhetorical) My next comment is part of (the long form of) my standard SO comment re (re)search. (In the case of meta the "manual" is the [help] (including its FAQ) & the [What's meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).)

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual & google [...] many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: I tried to explain as better as possible. When i was searching, i was not just looking for this Q title. And for me, the title seems to make sense: until where we can edit post, in terms on content/meaning. But I understand that people can don't understand.

Comment: I honestly don't believe that you actually think "the limit during editing", "the limit of an edit" or "be removed/edited/etc" are clear expressions of your question. (The very presence of the last shows you don't thing the ones before it are clear.) I encourage you to "make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly". PS When people say things like "for me" it frequently really means "not for me either (but I'm hoping someone will guess what I mean & it's enough to convince myself that I tried enough)". Good luck.

Comment: The ***first association*** for *"...limit during..."* may be some kind of time limit (e.g., the 5 minute edit grace period). Perhaps add something to your title that answers *"A limit for* ***what?"***