# Is suspending users for voting to delete a question while being discussed on meta reasonable?

Tags: discussion, meta, vote-to-delete, account-suspension

I found this question [Why is only the first case statement applied in a Google Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67873954/6699433) which is discussed on meta here [Regex question was closed as lacking details, but I think it was objective and clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408223/6699433)

What attracted my attention was a comment from moderator Cody Gray:

> **Moderator Note:** We will not be deleting questions while they are under active discussion on Meta. Please note that having participated in the deletion of this question within the next 48 hours will likely result in the suspension of your account.

I find this unacceptable. One should not have to read the comment section before voting to delete a question, even if it's preferable. And such harsh consequences are completely out of proportion. I might add that the [instructions for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) mentions nothing about this:

> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; [they can serve as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.

If a question should not be deleted while it's discussed on meta, then a feature for protecting the question from deletion should be implemented. This is discussed here: [Should posts that are actively being discussed on Meta be temporarily exempt from deletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408248/6699433)

But this question is about the suspension for such a (relatively) minor thing. Is it really reasonable to be suspended for not reading the comment section before voting to delete? Or for missing one single comment while doing so?

Clarification:

Note that I'm not saying that casting a delete vote is a minor thing. I'm saying that skipping comment section before doing so is a minor thing. And even more minor is missing one comment.

Comment: @Nick Nope. This question is mainly about the out of proportion consequences.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, I agree with klutt. While both questions are referring to the same mod comment, the other question doesn't really deal with details of any penalties, and how they should be applied. It's just asking for feedback on the broad principle, and whether it's worth making into a rule.

Comment: Oh, durr, I see your point now, this is about repercussions if you were to _break_ said rule, not the validity of the rule itself... I'm gunna go grab a coffee

Comment: IMO, a lock would be preferable. Yes, it prevents further answers/voting, but that's good, considering the question is clearly being discussed on meta.

Comment: If I had any recourse other than suspension to stop people from inappropriately using their delete votes, I would do so. However, I do not, so this is what you get. Note that deletion is a *privilege*, so you are responsible for how you exercise privileges granted by the system. If that means you have to pay attention to context and comments, well...OK.

Comment: using obscure comments and suspension treats instead of standard 2-days content dispute lock looks strange - can you please clarify this preference? @CodyGray

Comment: @gnat Content dispute locks prevent all interaction with the question. That's the *last* thing I want. People need to be able to vote on and edit questions when they're being discussed. What does *not* need to happen is deletion. I can't lock a question just from being deleted, so I have to lock the user accounts instead. It isn't ideal. If you want to fix this problem, propose a deletion-only lock, akin to our comments-only lock. Until that time, people are just going to have to continue to be individually responsible for how they exercise their delete-vote privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray What about an edited in notice instead, similar to the old style duplicate lists, that at least reduces the likelihood of it being missed (which appears to be one of the main concerns raised)?

Comment: @CodyGray I am a bit troubled when you're using the word privilege as if it was a great honor and something that only the delete voter benefits from. Sure, it's defined as a privilege, but in reality, we who cast all these votes are actually doing unpaid work to improve the site.

Comment: @klutt:  It actually *is* a privilege.  You can *lose* your privileges if you go down to 1 reputation, which is what happens if you're suspended.  Just because you do the work doesn't mean you're entitled to continue to do the work.

Comment: @Nick Sigh. The last thing I want is more noise in questions. But yeah, I guess if the problem is *really* that people are missing this notice, then I guess that would be fine. Evidence says literally nobody is missing it. It's gotten at least 2 Meta questions and multiple discussions in chat. Probably the bold text is working well enough.

Comment: In the case in question, exercising delete votes would not be improving the site. Rather, it would be an abuse of the delete-vote privilege (yes, it's still a privilege, even if we appreciate when people exercise that privilege) because it would be treating the delete vote as if it were a "super-downvote", which don't exist for a reason.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, I agree but.... *"One should not have to read the comment section before voting to delete a question, even if it's preferable."*, *"for not reading the comment section before voting to delete"*, *"obscure comments"*,...

Comment: @CodyGray SO is a long-term repository of knowledge. And I bet it can wait for 48 hours for whatever is needed to interact with question (no [urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) here please). I think that preference for suspending content contributors using obscure capricious tricks over standard, established and harmless measures goes against site purpose and spirit

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I know that it's defined as a privilege. But the site would suffer A LOT if the users stopped using their privileges.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, @gnat. When a post is deleted, it cannot be discussed, because the vast majority of people cannot see it. Additionally, people who are inappropriately using deleting votes are not content contributors. Precisely the opposite, in fact. Nor is suspension a "capricious trick"; it's practically the only recourse that moderators have. Nor are content locks "established and harmless measures". They are neither established in cases like this, nor are they anywhere close to harmless, because they prevent both voting and editing. I feel like I'm repeating myself...

Comment: @klutt Slippery slope fallacies aren't persuasive. Avoiding the deletion of a post that is under active discussion on Meta is not the same as users entirely stopping the use of their privileges.

Comment: Can moderators post a custom notice at the top of a post? Like the one of a bounty or a locked post? Asking because another option instead of locking could be a visible notice on the post with the same phrasing as Cody's discussed "moderator note"...

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, they can't add custom notices

Comment: Stopping the use of deletion when something is being discussed without stopping the use of votes puts a "thumb on the scale." If you actually wanted to treat meta discussions from a neutral objective PoV you'd lock them and then let the discussion happen before *any* action occurs on the post.

Comment: @Tomerikoo needs CM/staff intervention to customize the post notices.

Comment: The thumb on the scale was very much intentional. It's akin to clogging the drain while you're searching for something that was lost in the sink or tub. You don't want it to drain out until you have a chance to look. Of course, if we completely *froze* the contents of the sink/tub, that wouldn't be very useful, because then no one could actually look for the thing that was believed to be lost in it. The neutral, objective PoV is that people should be allowed to vote on, edit, and *view* the question. Deletion prevents that. @KevinB

Comment: Locking the post does not prevent people from seeing the question. Leaving it unlocked prevents people from seeing the question in the state it was in when the discussion started.

Comment: Locking the post prevents people from voting on or editing the question. As I believe I have mentioned once or twice before... Maybe what people are missing is why those are important. Well, the importance of voting should be self-evident: that's a way for people to give their opinion about the post. Think it should be deleted? *Downvote* it. What about editing? Well, the number one reason why questions are closed is they're unclear. The number one reason why questions are reopened is that they're edited. The number one way to argue for a question's reopening is by editing it.

Comment: Yes, and we now have roving bands of upvoters on meta.

Comment: The revision history shows the state the question was originally in when it was closed, in the rare event that that actually matters. The real point of these Meta questions isn't to discuss the past; it's to figure out the future. Disagreeing with the close voters isn't helpful, unless you can fix the problem and address their concerns.

Comment: Oh no!! UPVOTERS??!!! Whatever will we do????

Comment: Become more and more of a help desk year after year? a trash can of forgotten useless questions?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I'm just saying that privilege usually implies some kind of reward. Note the difference of the privilege "reduce ads" and "established user". That's something completely different to the privilege of doing unpaid work to improve the site. If someone really is misusing their votes, that's one thing. I completely understand that moderators have to act sometimes, and that suspension can be a valid option in those cases. But when you're talking about it the way you did here, you're really diminishing the work privileged users do here.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand what you don't understand. Content dispute lock prevents deletion. As for suspension, yes one you threated in there is obscure and capricious - because it is buried in comments, poorly justified and is inconsistent with site rules

Comment: I have no valuation whatsoever for the work people do when the sole purpose of that work is to prevent others from having an opinion. That's the only reason anyone would vote to delete that question while it was under active discussion, and it is an abuse vector that happens over and over and over again. It is a misuse of votes, in my opinion, and I'm done with it. I've addressed more times than I can count just in the comments here why locking is inappropriate, and why suspension is the normal course of action for someone who exercises site features/privileges in an incorrect way.

Comment: i would have deleted this question too, it is bad and should be immediately removed

Comment: I've also had quite enough of this absolutely ridiculous slippery slope fallacy that upvoting is somehow incompatible with having quality content on the site, or that holding off on deletion of something while it is under active discussion on Meta is somehow devaluing the work that people put into curating this site. It's not as if leaving a single question that at least one person is actively working to improve is turning the site into a trash can. Not sure if you're aware, but I've put a lot of effort into curating this site over the years, none of it for any payment.

Comment: Come on, seriously? "it is bad and should be immediately removed" isn't even an argument. It doesn't even *attempt* to justify why the question is bad. Furthermore, immediate removal is not the normal course of action to something that is bad. You close these posts, and downvote these posts, and then, hopefully, *edit* these posts. @nbk

Comment: it was closed two times has multiple duplicates, @CodyGray the tome this question was discusse3d was more than over, so the suspensions is a swrong as ropening that thread

Comment: @CodyGray Sole purpose of preventing others from having an opinion? Sorry, but what are you talking about? Those who cast a downvote might not even know it's under discussion.

Comment: @CodyGray "Content dispute locks prevent all interaction with the question. That's the last thing I want. People need to be able to vote on and edit questions when they're being discussed. What does not need to happen is deletion." Are you aware that deletion is also a vote and interaction right? Also, that people can see a screenshot right?

Comment: @Braiam Obviously he is aware? And obviously he wants to continue allowing users to interact with up/down/close votes and edits (which can't be done to deleted posts), while at the same not allowing the post to be deleted. That seems blatantly obvious to me. -- What good is seeing a screenshot if we want people to interact with a post without deleting it? -- *"Content dispute locks prevent all interaction with the question."* - The issue here being we don't want to prevent _all_ interaction, we want to prevent _a specific_ interaction.

Comment: @Nick if so, then every hope is lost. If moderators don't want content to be deleted, but only on the extreme cases, then we can no longer call ourself a library of high quality content. Just a Yahoo Answers.

Comment: @Braiam as usual you appear to be missing the nuances here. Where does it say moderators don’t want *any* content deleted?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, the nuance isn't missing on me. That I would get suspended because I used my privilege to act on the content on the site in the way I'm supposed to. That message was load and clear.

Comment: I mean... when a moderator goes from *"Stack Overflow is not a help desk."* to 4 years later actively preventing curation on what is clearly a useless question... we don't really need to make assumptions.

Comment: @Braiam we expect you to use common sense and act responsibly. If you can’t figure out how to do either then you are indeed going to get into trouble. Why is that surprising to you, or so terribly upsetting?

Comment: @KevinB you really can’t wait 48 hours with deleting a single post? There is such a thing as giving other processes priority that everyone feels are important too, such as giving the community a chance to discuss a specific post for a few days without that post being locked away from the majority of users. Once that process is done the good ole priorities of content curation can triumph again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in this case, clearly not. By not locking it, it is now not fixable. (Unless, of course, a mod decides to step in)

Comment: @KevinB not fixable *how*. We *are* effectively locking it, from deletion. It’s just a bit more manual a process.

Comment: @MartijnPieters common sense is not so common, as I'm painfully aware. Like the common sense that we as curators can remove content of the site that doesn't add to the corpus of high quality questions about programming. If you want the content to be available to anyone that is reading the discussion use screenshots. It's the way since delete votes are a thing. I don't see how that method is particularly limiting in any way/form.

Comment: @Braiam there is lots of things you can’t delete, it is hardly a universal feature. And common sense would tell *me* that throwing a tantrum over not being able to cast a delete vote on a post for 48 hours would be silly. Just wait a bit.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure in 48 hours the 30 people who upvoted this garbage will come to their senses

Comment: @KevinB is that what is upsetting you? That other people on the internet disagree with you, have cast an upvote on a post you disagree deserves to be upvoted and you are now prevented from getting your way?

Comment: What bothers me is it seems the moderators have jumped ship. What happened this place being a repository of useful questions and answers rather than a help desk

Comment: @KevinB let’s not go round in circles on that one. 48h != no deletion, ever. All this fuss because you have to wait two days.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The issue is that this will be harder to do now. And question not being deleted is the least of our problems. It is a message that is being sent. It was unclear question to begin with and it is dupe. And in all this process OP didn't lift his finger to clarify or even interact with others in any way. Now we have OP that has poor track record in asking questions, free to ask more because he got completely undeserved upvotes on that question.  We cannot seriously moderate influx of all the crap, if we have our hands tied.

Comment: I'd find arguments like Kevin and Dalija's far more compelling if [the question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67873954) had turned into complete crap while the 48 hours were playing out. However, in my estimation, the exact opposite happened. Something that was a pretty poor question has turned into a much better question because we had a discussion about it, and, more importantly, because editing remained available the entire time. I certainly don't care whether OP is involved, not now or ever. The only message being sent is that we allow chances for redemption.

Comment: @CodyGray It is still a duplicate question. People have worked hard to remove regex part only to make it SQL CASE duplicate. It is not improvement in any way. It is not the worst question, but it is far from being even satisfactory question (the regex part is still unclear) I am all for redemption, but this is really poor example, especially since OP is totally silent (I cannot see if there were any comments that were deleted, but in that case I would expect some other comments to be deleted, too).

Comment: @CodyGray "Something that was a pretty poor question has turned into a much better question because we had a discussion about it" and was done **to spite** anyone that participated in that discussion **including you**. You ain't doing me any favors, and if I knew that you would adopt the position you had adopted, I would stopped at just  downvoting the question without editing it instead of doing both.

Comment: Sorry to have made you part of the solution, @Braiam. I'm sure someone else would have been willing to stand up and help, had you not.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting questions (or answers) *isn't* minor.

You're removing something from public view on the site, and that should only be done in extreme cases - for instance, the post is something that is genuinely ***so*** radioactive that deleting it would preserve the *rest* of us from getting irradiated while at work or in the presence of others who might find that kind of content unsavory.

Deleting it *just* to delete the content is highly disruptive since moderators get flagged about undelete wars (e.g. groups of motivated actors toggling the state of a question between undeleted and deleted), and they have to do *something* about that.

That's *probably* why the moderator in question made that statement.

Personally I view it as a reasonable thing to state since maybe everyone needs to cool their jets on deleting a post like this (honestly not seeing my Geiger counter respond to it), and let the conversation about it on Meta unfold before a larger community action takes place.

Comment: this is wrong. Mod comment states 48 hours meaning that after this delay they are OK with deletion. Which makes one wonder, why using obscure comments and suspension treats instead of standard 2-days content dispute lock

Comment: @gnat because delaying 48 hours while allowing votes means it *will* receive enough upvotes to prevent deletion, thus fulfilling the real goal behind such a statement.

Comment: No, literally, the real goal behind such a statement was to allow the Meta discussion to happen while people were actively engaged. If the conclusion reached on Meta was that it should be deleted, then it would be fine to delete it. That's why I put a 48-hour clock on there. I thought that was a reasonable minimum amount of time to allow for discussion. Moderators don't have auto-deleting comments, either.

Comment: Thank you. I clarified my question a bit. The minor thing is not about deletion, but skipping reading comment section before deletion.

Comment: @KevinB I'm confused why people keep talking about upvotes. Don't votes (generated by meta effect or not) work in both directions? Disclaimer: I did not upvote or downvote the question being discussed. I just don't understand the logic behind the "fear of upvotes". Maybe I'm missing something though.

Comment: No, unfortunately, the people who downvote poor quality content are a disproportionately small minority.

Comment: "should only be done in extreme cases" nononono. A library of high quality questions and answers do not have drivel content. That content is removed.

Comment: @KevinB I don't know if that's true. On many occasions, I've seen questions downvoted to oblivion due to the meta effect.

Comment: I have too, though, it feels times have changed. people don't seem to have an issue with the opposite extreme. The question being discussed here is a textbook X/Y question with a title that doesn't describe the problem. It's unlikely to be of use to anyone in the future, much less to any of the people who upvoted it.

Comment: @CodyGray if you want discussion, use screenshots, like it has been done since forever.

Comment: @KevinB:  [There's a whole separate Meta question that you can raise that point on, you know.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408223/1079354)  All that is needed is just some participation with others who seem to disagree with your viewpoint that this question *must* be deleted.  Know that I'm not hard against deletion of any kind; I just prefer justification for those kinds of actions.  Deleting content shouldn't be done as lightly as it is today.

Comment: I am aware, my comment wasn't raising an issue related to that question specifically. It's most certainly not the only recent example of this occuring.

Comment: @Braiam As a user who can't see deleted content: Screenshots are a poor substitute. It prevents me from seeing the history, for example. It also prevents visually impaired users from joining the discussion.

Comment: @ModusTollens I'm also a user that haven't been able to see deleted content since forever on SO... you ain't missing much. Also, history is usually given on the question if and when it's relevant. All in all, the argument is flimsy at best.

Comment: @Braiam What if I want to see the history of the question to prove my point on the question, but I can't see it? What if someone cannot see the image because imgur is blocked for them? There's a reason we don't like images of code. A question under discussion should not be hidden.

Comment: @10Rep Ask and you shall receive

Comment: @KevinB What if imgur is blocked for someone? I shouldn't have to ask, I should be able to see if by default.

Comment: @10Rep - more so, it *is* blocked for people, [for example in China](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407423/11407695)

Comment: Given that SO has no interest in resolving that, neither do I

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah, that is exactly what I was referring to, but I couldn't quite place my finger on that question...

Comment: @KevinB - well... given how many things SE has no interest in fixing we should realistically ditch the network and go mind our own business :) But for the sake of those who still care - why not fix something that we actually can fix (like not requiring screenshots to discuss)? Although I must admit that's not that big of an issue.

Comment: Earn the privilege like everyone else had to.

Comment: @KevinB - I'll earn mine in time, don't worry. What I, however, do not understand is how come you think "everyone else" *earned* it? There are plenty of users with a couple of old popular posts that never cared about moderation, yet they have the privilege.  I am a supporter of reasonable restrictions but come on, moderation should not depend on something *passively* accumulated. What's more, can get elected IRL with less time and effort than it takes to view deleted questions. I maintain a firm stance that restricting deleted posts to 10K is unreasonable.

Comment: that sounds like a problem that is quite different from the question at hand.

Comment: @OlegValter and you found the conundrum: to get the reputation you have to "feel dirty" answering crappy questions, the ones that are dime in a dozen. As I wrote elsewhere, you will not be missing much and as Kevin said, you can ask if the morbid curiosity gets the best of you.

Comment: @Braiam yeah, exactly - which I think is not very reasonable since moderation privileges should not incentivize such behavior. Personally, I do not hesitate to ask when I want a screenshot, and I am certain I will reach the threshold in due time, just wanted to provide support for the people who care about moderation but find that they can't even see anything due to arbitrary restrictions. P.s. The only issue I have with the "you are not missing much" is that it supposes that one can *convince* another how they should feel about something (i.e. to not be invested)...

Comment: @OlegValter I mean, aren't you here for practical programming questions? If it's deleted, it's very likely that is not one of those three adjectives.

Comment: @Braiam yeah, chances are high, but not *that* high. I am also not talking about *already* deleted posts, only about those who suddenly go out of scope in the midst of a discussion because of an unreasonable privilege system. Anyways, my personal stake here is close to zero, to be honest - in a sense, I do agree with you that others do not miss much.

Comment: @OlegValter for me a question removed 10 years ago and 1 second ago are the same: information that if I really want, I can always ask it.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding whether it's reasonable to expect delete voters to read the comments...

#### **Yes**, you should be reading the entire page before voting to delete.

The [help center for the 10k privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says (emphasis added):

> #### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions ***that are of no lasting value whatsoever*** should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are any good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

In order to determine if the question is "of no lasting value whatsoever," you need to read the question, any answers, and the comments to ensure that there's no valuable information there.  Information in comments is exactly why the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) takes comments into account when deciding whether to delete unanswered zero-score questions.  Delete voters should also be taking this into account when deciding whether to delete content.

Comment: What you refer to the "the entire page"? Do comments, which are second class citizen, reach the bar? Or only the question and answers themselves?

Comment: @Braiam You should generally read the entire post, including comments, so that you don't miss any important info. Just because the docs don't _specifically_ mention reading comments doesn't mean one should just delete questions like that. Even the Roomba doesn't delete a post if it has more than 1 comment.

Answer (score -7):

> I find this unacceptable. One should not have to read the comment section before voting to delete a question, even if it's preferable. And such harsh consequences are completely out of proportion. I might add that the instructions for deletion mentions nothing about this:

Wrong. Before voting to delete a question, one should check to see if a question is being discussed on meta. If it is, there's almost always going to be a comment that says "This post is being discussed on meta". *Deleting a question is a very powerful and dangerous action*.

Moreover, by deleting a question that's being discussed on meta, you are shutting the discussion down from a lot of users. If a <10k user wants to pitch in and give their opinion, they can no longer do so because the post is not viewable for them. They cannot interact with it, either.

Moderators are exception handlers; as such, they have to handle conflicts between the community. Since, at the moment, there is no way to prevent delete votes on a question, moderators would have to do the only thing left to them, that is, suspend the users who delete a question that's under discussion.

Also, the moderator did *not* suspend the users who originally delete voted the question. Instead, they gave a warning ***in bold*** that if you delete voted it after the message, you would get suspended. So it's OK if you accidentally delete vote a question that's being discussed on meta, because you won't get suspended immediately.

Read the [moderators comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873954/why-is-only-the-first-case-statement-applied-in-a-google-data-studio/67877709#comment119985817_67873954):

> Moderator Note: We will not be deleting questions while they are under active discussion on Meta. Please note that having participated in the deletion of this question ***within the next 48 hours*** will likely result in the suspension of your account.

In other words, the suspension kicks in if you delete vote the question *even after being warned*.

And a question lock, as already mentioned, will prevent *all interactions* with the post. Unless the community is abusing these interactions (in which case mods will lock the post), it shouldn't be question locked to prevent delete voters from deleting. That's just not fair, to say the least. Interactions with the post can change meta opinion on a post.

Until a lock which prevents delete/close/reopen votes is implemented, the moderators have to enforce this rule.

Comment: It's not wrong that the deletion instructions for trusted users make no mention of any of this. Many questions get deleted by users daily. A lot of them get a delete vote within minutes of close The percentage that show up as being discussed on meta is likely very small

Comment: @charlietfl never said it wasn’t ok.

Comment: Just suggesting that your categorical "Wrong." references statements that are not wrong, part of which is correct in some docs and another part is opinion

Comment: @charlietfl alright but dont be surprised when you get suspended if you break this rule which the mod crafted. Also, did you read the rest of my answer?

Answer (score -15):

**NO**

We already have the exact tool for this use case - [question locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/336163). If a moderator feels that a question is controversial enough that discussion must be held before anyone else jumps in and takes their own action, then the question needs to be locked. The FAQ post that I linked to even discusses these scenarios - that the lock is intended to stop close, etc. wars while a dispute is being resolved.

Comment: I'd like to be able to downvote the question (or answers) if they deserve being downvoted.  A lock keeps us boxed out from doing that because a few people with higher privileges decided to abuse deletion.

Comment: Content locks are completely inappropriate in cases like this, as they prevent both voting and editing. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408289/suspended-for-voting-to-delete-a-question-thats-discussed-on-meta-reasonable/408291#comment847907_408289

Comment: @Makoto nothing stops you from voting as you wish after lock expires (that is, if you have a real long-standing motivation for that, and not an intermittent impulse caused by a heat of a meta discussion)

Comment: @gnat Nothing prevents voting to delete a question after the discussion ends, either, which is a point I have yet to see addressed.

Comment: @zcoop98 the state pretty much every question that has been brought up in meta recently ends up in, directly prevents deletion regardless of what discussion occurs.

Comment: If pretty much every question that has been brought up on Meta ends up being improved to the point where it is reopened and does not need to be deleted, then... it sounds like we do not have a problem.

Comment: I fully understand that such a scenario is preferable, when your stance is keeping everything.